# Splitting a hex string into a list in Python - How?

Tags: python, string

If I have this string:

```
hexstring = '001122334455'
```

How can I split that into a list so the result is:

hexlist = ['00', '11', '22', '33', '44', '55']

I can't think of a nice, pythonic way to do this :/

Answer (score 15):

```
>>> [hexstring[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(hexstring), 2)]
['00', '11', '22', '33', '44', '55']
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively:

```
>>> hexstring = "01234567"
>>> it=iter(hexstring); [a+b for a,b in zip(it, it)]
['01', '23', '45', '67']
```

Use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead of `zip` if you're targeting Python 2.x.

This method is a specific version of `grouper` in the itertools recipe.

---

Some micro-benchmarks:

```
$ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"*500' '[hexstring[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0,len(hexstring), 2)]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 409 usec per loop

$ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"*500' '[hexstring[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(hexstring), 2)]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 438 usec per loop

$ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"*500' 'it=iter(hexstring); [a+b for a,b in zip(it, it)]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 526 usec per loop

$ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"*500; from itertools import izip' 'it=iter(hexstring); [a+b for a,b in izip(it, it)]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 406 usec per loop

$ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"*500; import re; r=re.compile(".{1,2}"); f=r.findall' 'f(hexstring)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 458 usec per loop

$ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"*500' '[hexstring[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(hexstring), 2)]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 756 usec per loop

$ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"*500' 'it=iter(hexstring); [a+b for a,b in zip(it, it)]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 414 usec per loop

$ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"*500; import re; r=re.compile(".{1,2}"); f=r.findall' 'f(hexstring)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 865 usec per loop


$ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"' '[hexstring[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0,len(hexstring), 2)]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 usec per loop

$ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"' '[hexstring[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(hexstring), 2)]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 usec per loop

$ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"' 'it=iter(hexstring); [a+b for a,b in zip(it, it)]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.78 usec per loop

$ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"; from itertools import izip' 'it=iter(hexstring); [a+b for a,b in izip(it, it)]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.39 usec per loop

$ python2.6 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"; import re; r=re.compile(".{1,2}"); f=r.findall' 'f(hexstring)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 usec per loop

$ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"' '[hexstring[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(hexstring), 2)]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.46 usec per loop

$ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"' 'it=iter(hexstring); [a+b for a,b in zip(it, it)]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.84 usec per loop

$ python3.1 -m timeit -s 'hexstring = "01234567"; import re; r=re.compile(".{1,2}"); f=r.findall' 'f(hexstring)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.07 usec per loop
```

Observation:

- With long strings on Python 2.6, [@SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170718/splitting-a-hex-string-into-a-list-in-python-how/3170728#3170728)'s and my method are fastest. Of course you need to use lazy iterators e.g. `xrange` and `izip`.
- With short strings on Python 2.6, [@Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170718/splitting-a-hex-string-into-a-list-in-python-how/3171210#3171210)'s regular expression is fastest.
- On Python 3.1 my method is fastest in both cases, but I believe it's because Python 3.x is less optimized.
- Of course, [premature optimization is evil, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178045/when-should-you-start-optimising-code).

Answer (score 3):

A slightly odd way:

```
map(''.join,zip(hexstring[::2],hexstring[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('.{1, 2}', '001122334455')
['00', '11', '22', '33', '44', '55']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hexstring = "01234567"
[''.join(x) for x in zip(*[iter(hexstring)]*2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional style:

```
>>> result = map(lambda x,y : x+y, *[iter('0013A20040522BAA')]*2)
>>> tuple(result)
('00', '13', 'A2', '00', '40', '52', '2B', 'AA')
```

or yet a other variation around `zip` as suggested before:

```
>>> result = (a+b for a,b in zip(*[iter('0013A20040522BAA')]*2))
>>> tuple(result)
('00', '13', 'A2', '00', '40', '52', '2B', 'AA')
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this?Some binary got single(), some got(\), some \\ and unknown (hex?) like x99wh

(b'E\x00\x00(H\xd2@\x00\x80\x06\xa1J\xc0\xa8\x01!=[\x11\x8f\xc5[\x01\xbb\x99wh\xcd\\xb2\xcdQP\x10\x82t)M\x00\x00', ('192.168.1.33', 0))

Using socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW) on window

Here is linux sample.
http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/